# Interactive Brokers API cancelOrders not working

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I have the following function that should cancel an Order given its ID:

```
def cancel_order(clientId, cancel_order_id, app=None):  
    while app == None or app.isConnected() is False:
        app = IBapi().connection(clientId)
        
    print(f'canceling {cancel_order_id}')
    print(f'clientId {app.clientId}')

    app.cancelOrder(cancel_order_id, "")
```

And the terminal output is as follows:

[image]

But nothing happens, the order in the TWS Workstation remains the same...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
time.sleep(1)
```

after

```
app.cancelOrder(cancel_order_id, "")
```

Solved the issue temporarily.

Meaning a logic for waiting (more reliable than "1") should be implemented.